# Linux mint error while installing and updating software

Tags: linux, python, linux-mint, mysql

My PC runs linux mint cinnamon 19 with kernel `4.20.0-042000-generic 64-bit`.
When I try to install software via terminal or update programs via Update manager, I get the following error:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-connector-python_8.0.14-1ubuntu18.04_all.deb: 
new mysql-connector-python package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Were there any more error messages? Does the installed package still work ok?

Comment: this is the error, and no, if I try updating programs from update manager it fails and says the update failed because of the above error

Comment: This applies to any and all software updates and installations?

Comment: it applies to all things i try to update via update manager, including stuff like PDF utilities and image viewer updates, and it also prevents me from installing MySQL via terminal\software centre